# PhoneInputWithCountry component can not set value by event

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-phone-number-input

I'm using PhoneInputWithCountry component from react-phone-number-input on Next.js 14.
I want to set value on the PhoneInputWithCountry component when user clicks checkbox.
So I set the value as 'defaultValue' and 'Value' property, but it doesn't work.
Could you help me to set the value?

```
export default function Home() {
  const { control } = useForm();
  const [tel, setTel] = useState("");
  const specialTel = "+1 604 111 1111";

  // fill tel value * it doesn't set
  const fillValue = (isChecked: boolean) => {
    if (isChecked == true) {
      setTel(specialTel);
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-[150px]" style={{ width: "150px" }}>
        <label htmlFor="specialTel">Set Special Tel</label>
        <input
          id="specialTel"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(event) => fillValue(event.target.checked)}
        />
        <PhoneInputWithCountry
          name="tel"
          value={tel}
          defaultValue={tel}
          control={control}
          countries={["CA"]}
          addInternationalOption={false}
          defaultCountry="CA"
          min={10}
          international={true}
          limitMaxLength={true}
          onChange={(val: string) => {
            console.log(val);
            setTel(val);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/can-not-set-default-value-of-the-phoneinputwithcountry-forked-pf4yjp?file=%2Fpackage-lock.json%3A51%2C42&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0007356nqa70zzvj%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0002356n904qv1aj%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0004356nhabgee22%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0006356nm0j17wsy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqfj0zmx0002356n904qv1aj%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0002356n904qv1aj%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmw0001356nzybjurmx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqflq3310002356njub9ecr7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A51%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A42%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A51%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A42%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage-lock.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqflq3310002356njub9ecr7%2522%257D%252C%2522clqfj0zmx0006356nm0j17wsy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0006356nm0j17wsy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqfledyt020c356ng1vi4q9n%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfledyt020c356ng1vi4q9n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqfj0zmx0004356nhabgee22%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0004356nhabgee22%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj0zmx0003356n2pjcghms%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj5w4c00w2356nif3u7gc5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqfj5xur00nyefgef7ccel6l%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522install%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfj94uz013m356nbr5xxg68%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqfj94uz013m356nbr5xxg68%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: event.target.checked == true isn't firing, so check that first. But not signing up to another service to help troubleshoot. Best to follow the question guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Based on the following, I can not use PhoneInputWithCountry when I want to set value
after rendered. Because it doesn't accept 'value' property.
https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/-/issues/72

So, I have to use other components(e.g. PhoneInputWithCountrySelect).
About my code, just need to import 'PhoneInputWithCountrySelect' and change PhoneInputWithCountry to PhoneInputWithCountrySelect then it works.

```
return (
    ....
      <PhoneInputWithCountrySelect
        name="tel"
        value={tel}
        defaultValue={tel}
        control={control}
        countries={["CA"]}
        addInternationalOption={false}
        defaultCountry="CA"
        min={10}
        international={true}
        limitMaxLength={true}
        onChange={(val: string) => {
          console.log(val);
          setTel(val);
        }}
      />
  ...
);
```